# Google sheets - tranposing certain column to rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have the link to my sample google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tyy7LsdXULAw09hE8yeJOyVfsziHiApXjdkK3-13E9c/edit#gid=1854242803

My data sample is like Sheet1, and the output I'm trying to get is in Sheet 2. Basically, the Cells C4:C9 in Sheet 1, and put to Cells C8:C14 in Sheet 2 (and many more similar columns). So I want to ‘cascade’ the rows in this way.

Edit: What I've tried was basic moving each column with their own function,column by column. But its not so efficient, with each column having their own function. Is there some more elegant way?

Comment: Hi @NewGirl, can you make your spreadsheet accesible so others can see it as well? Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve - can you please provide the things you have tried in order to accomplish this as well?

Comment: @ale13 I have edited my post

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve - if you just want to transpose the `YEAR` & `WEEK` column, why aren't you using the `TRANSPOSE` function? @NewGirl

Comment: but how do i do that and still maintain the other rows?

Comment: Which other rows? Can you please be more specific and eventually include some before/after screenshots of your Spreadsheet?

Comment: but i put the before in Sheet1 , and the after in Sheet2 . Sheet2 is what i want to achieve..

Comment: Do you have any formulas associated with the cells in `Sheet1`? Or is it just plain data? @NewGirl